# Using Run Functional Test Tasks with SpecFLow and Selenium DLL

Tags: tfs, specflow, nunit-3.0

I am having a serious problem with distributed tests using Run Functional Test Tasks.

My scenario is: I build and run unit tests OK for Selenium and SpecFLow. After, I copy  DLLs for test environment machine, install test agente and I run Functional Test Task. The agent installation is ok but running Specflow and Selenium DLL is my problem.

On first try, I copied only Specflow and Selenium DLL for the machine tests and I have this error:

```
2016-06-30T23:12:19.5087649Z DistributedTests: Test run '327' is in 'InProgress' state.

2016-06-30T23:12:29.5121638Z DistributedTests: Test run '327' is in 'InProgress' state.

2016-06-30T23:12:39.5531864Z DistributedTests: Test run '327' is in 'InProgress' state.

2016-06-30T23:12:49.5714200Z DistributedTests: Test run '327' is in 'InProgress' state.

2016-06-30T23:12:59.5907849Z DistributedTests: Test run '327' is in 'InProgress' state.

2016-06-30T23:13:09.6050718Z DistributedTests: Test run '327' is in 'InProgress' state.

2016-06-30T23:13:19.6276865Z DistributedTests: Test run '327' is in 'InProgress' state.

2016-06-30T23:13:29.6528948Z DistributedTests: Test run '327' is in 'Aborted' state.

2016-06-30T23:13:39.6659731Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.

2016-06-30T23:13:39.6972230Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: New test run created.

2016-06-30T23:13:39.7128461Z ##[warning]Test Run queued for Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION).

2016-06-30T23:13:39.7128461Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test discovery started.

2016-06-30T23:13:39.7128461Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test Run Discovery Aborted . Test run id : 327

2016-06-30T23:13:39.7128461Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: UnExpected error occured during test execution. Try again.

2016-06-30T23:13:39.7128461Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Error : No tests were discovered from the specified test sources

2016-06-30T23:13:39.7128461Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run aborted. Test run id: 327

2016-06-30T23:13:39.8690942Z ##[error]The test run was aborted, failing the task.
```

I also tried to copy all DLLs including SpecFLow and Selenium DLL plus Web site DLL and it still returning the same error. All is configured ok. For the last try, I have installed VSStudio into test environment and nothing happens.

I have one test environment similar and it is running OK.
EDIT

[Agent Deployment Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfW7z.png)

[Run Functional Test Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVEMB.png)

Comment: What test framework are you using? Also, it's important to note that in the software development world the term *unit test* has a very specific meaning, and Selenium tests are **not** unit tests.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your build definition? As you mentioned you have one test environment similar and it is running OK, do you mean if you run Run Functional Test Tasks on this test environment, the test will be running without issue?

Comment: Yes. When I run same Run Functional Test task on test environment it is OK.

Comment: I am running with SpecFlow integrated with NUnit 3.0.

Comment: Ever figure out what's going on here, having identical issues

Comment: I have solved this problem. During my release task, I copy Nunit.dll for directory that contains Specflow.dll. Now, it is working fine.